# Parse aspnet settings from Azure Portal to Json format

Tags: parsing, asp.net-core

```
       { 
            { "IdentityServer:Host", "local.example.com" }, 
            { "IdentityServer:ClientId", "MyClientId" },  
            { "SlackApi:WebhookUrl",  "https://hooks.slack.com/services/Some/Url" },  
            { "SlackApi:DisplayName", "Slack bot" } 
        };
```

This is what I get from Azure Portal. I would like this converted to a json format for localsettings.json in aspnetcore.

```
{
"IdentityServer":{
    "Host": "local.example.com",
    "ClientId": "MyClientId"
},
"SlackApi": {
    "WebhookUrl":"https://hooks.slack.com/services/Some/Url",
    "DisplayName":"Slack bot" 
}
}
```

Comment: Is this for a one time conversion? Something you need to do as part of an automated migration? Or something you’re trying to do e.g., each time your application runs?

Comment: To my knowledge there isn’t a built in way to do this; you’d likely need to parse the returned JSON and reconstruct it in the target schema.

Comment: Its something i would like to once and keep a console based c# program which I can when required for a particular env in Azure